# Editing pods in xcode project - enabling edits to be compiled

Tags: ios, build, cocoapods

I often use pods in my Obj-C and Swift projects and quite often need to tweak a pod for my use-cases. I noted recently that my edits were having no effect, that the original bits were being used, and there were many times I was stumped at a situation that I thought my editing corrected, only to realize the compiled bits did not include my latest brilliant hack.

Then I discovered that simply cleaning the build folder (shift-cmd-K) will reset everything and the next build incorporates my edits. I now do this as a matter of regular business with each pod edit, but wondered if there was a simpler way to set a pod to be included in each rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Editing pods is not ideal, simply because all your changes will be removed after the next `pod update`.

The best way here would be to fork the pod, modify it and use your own version instead.

Comment: I agree, but often times when time is an issue, that just takes too long. I mark each edit for easy recall, and i backup like a drunk monkey, so always have my efforts on hand. But good suggestion, perhaps that will also bump up my github cred.

Comment: It will definitely save you time in the long run, because you won't need to re-make your changes each time you update pods.